# "The method put(Object, Object) in the type HashMap is not applicable for the arguments (String, boolean)"

Tags: java, hashmap

```
hm.put("billingEnquiry",true);
```

produces the error

```
The method put(Object, Object) in the type HashMap is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String,boolean)".
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: true is not an object. You need a Boolean not a boolean. Or you need to upgrade to jdk 1.5 or newer.

Comment: *boolean* is a primitive type, *Boolean* is an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably using a non-parametrized HashMap. 
Try to declare your HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

Also note that you cannot use primitive types in generic types. 
So this:

```
HashMap<String, boolean> myMap = new HashMap<String, boolean>();
```

... is **incorrect** and won't even compile.

Comment: On a Java 5+ VM, the boolean would be autoboxed to a Boolean, whether the map is generic or not. It's not autoboxed, so it's not a Java 5+ VM, so generic maps don't exist yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
hm.put("billingEnquiry",Boolean.TRUE);
```

`boolean` with a lower case b is a primitive not an object.